# C++BUILDER OnVirtualKeyboardShown and OnVirtualKeyboardHidden firing from another form

Tags: android, c++, c++builder

I have a project to Mobile (Android and IOS) in C++Builder Tokyo 10.2.
It has 3 forms (yet) and all of them have some TEdits.
Each form has his own 'FormVirtualKeyboardShown' and 'FormVirtualKeyboardHidden' functions.
And I Have a 'Focused->GetObject()' in each one (FormVirtualKeyboardShown function) to get which TEdit is Focus.

The problem is: ALL of 'FormVirtualKeyboardShown' functions are FIRING, no matter which Form is calling. 
I tryed to change the names of the function in .CPP, .H and .FMX files, make the name of the function unique to all of my project.
But still not working. It is calling ALL of the functions in all forms.

Because of that, I get a error message in the line that has the dynamic_cast code.

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project Project1.apk raised exception class Segmentation fault (11).
```

Its trying to get the TEdit from another Form and then gets a error. 
I´m new in FMX and I´ve never seen something like that. 
Here is part of my codes:

Unit1.cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormVirtualKeyboardShown(TObject *Sender, bool KeyboardVisible,const TRect &Bounds)
{
    int num;
    TControl * LFocused = dynamic_cast<TControl*>(Focused->GetObject());
    num = LFocused->ComponentIndex;
    ShowMessage("Index of TEdit from Form ONE is "+ IntToStr(num));
}
```

Unit2.cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm2::FormVirtualKeyboardShown(TObject *Sender, bool KeyboardVisible,const TRect &Bounds)
{
    int num;
    TControl * LFocused = dynamic_cast<TControl*>(Focused->GetObject());
    num = LFocused->ComponentIndex;
    ShowMessage("Index of TEdit from Form TWO is "+ IntToStr(num));
}
```

Unit3.cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm3::FormVirtualKeyboardShown(TObject *Sender, bool KeyboardVisible,const TRect &Bounds)
{
    int num;
    TControl * LFocused = dynamic_cast<TControl*>(Focused->GetObject());
    num = LFocused->ComponentIndex;
    ShowMessage("Index of TEdit from Form THREE is "+ IntToStr(num));
}
```

My point is: I need to Know exactly which TEdit is Focus. So i can take the actions properly.

Do i need to make these functions (FormVirtualKeyboardShown and FormVirtualKeyboardHidden) only in Unit1.cpp (Form1)?. 
So ALL the TEdits in another forms will fire these functions in Form1.
If so... how can I identify which TEdit has focus? From any Form???

I am using C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo 25.0.26309.314

Please help me guys!
Thank you!

Comment: "*I get a error message in the line that has the dynamic_cast code*" - you did not say what the error actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on why multiple Forms would fire the same VirtualKeyboard events at the same time.  Sounds like a bug in FireMonkey to me.  Unless the `KeyboardVisible` parameter is `true` in only one event and is `false` in the other two events, which would be a weird design choice.

But even so, this should be fairly simple to work around, eg:

Unit1.cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormVirtualKeyboardShown(TObject *Sender, bool KeyboardVisible, const TRect &Bounds)
{
    if (!KeyboardVisible) return;
    _di_IControl ctrl = Focused;
    if (!ctrl) return;
    if (Screen->FocusControl != ctrl) return;
    TControl * LFocused = static_cast<TControl*>(ctrl->GetObject());
    int num = LFocused->ComponentIndex;
    ShowMessage("Index of TEdit from Form ONE is " + IntToStr(num));
}
```

Unit2.cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm2::FormVirtualKeyboardShown(TObject *Sender, bool KeyboardVisible,const TRect &Bounds)
{
    if (!KeyboardVisible) return;
    _di_IControl ctrl = Focused;
    if (!ctrl) return;
    if (Screen->FocusControl != ctrl) return;
    TControl * LFocused = static_cast<TControl*>(ctrl->GetObject());
    int num = LFocused->ComponentIndex;
    ShowMessage("Index of TEdit from Form TWO is " + IntToStr(num));
}
```

Unit3.cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm3::FormVirtualKeyboardShown(TObject *Sender, bool KeyboardVisible,const TRect &Bounds)
{
    if (!KeyboardVisible) return;
    _di_IControl ctrl = Focused;
    if (!ctrl) return;
    if (Screen->FocusControl != ctrl) return;
    TControl * LFocused = static_cast<TControl*>(ctrl->GetObject());
    int num = LFocused->ComponentIndex;
    ShowMessage("Index of TEdit from Form THREE is " + IntToStr(num));
}
```

Comment: WONDERFUL REMY It worked perfectly.
It really looks like a bug. 
How can a Function could call another function(the same name) from another form?
I thought it could be BECAUSE THE SAME NAME. 
But like i said, I tryed to change but it didnt work.
Sorry for the mistake of error message. 
I edit the post and put the error message.

THANK YOU A LOT REMY.